# Return true if any value of vector is in list

Tags: r

Let's say I haved a dataframe that contains a column called `member_id`. Sometimes `member_id` will be a single numeric value, other times it will be a comma-delimited list of all the `member_id`'s a given user has.

I want to filter out all rows of a dataframe where `member_id` is not in some list, let's call that list: `finalized_list`.  I cannot figure out how to implicitly iterate over the cells which contain comma-delimited lists and return TRUE if any of them are in the finalized_list.

I can't seem to figure out how to put a vector inside a specific cell in the dataframe for a reproducible example, but imagine something like the following:

e.g.

```
data <- data.frame(member_id = c('100', '200',  list(c('300','400')), '400', '500'))
finalized_list <- c('100', '200', '300')
```

I tried to do something like:

```
complete_df <- data[data$member_id %in% finalized_list, ]
```

but this will not correctly handle the values that are lists like c(300, 400).  I thought `any` might be resolve the issue:

```
complete_df <- data[any(data$member_id %in% finalized_list), ]
```

But this also did not work.

Thoughts?

Comment: Something's wrong with your `data` example. If you want the value to be a comma separated list, you should use `paste0(c('300','400'), collapse = ',')` instead of `list(c('300','400'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data <- data.frame(member_id = c('100', '200',  paste0(c('300','400'), collapse = ','), '400', '500'))
finalized_list <- c('100', '200', '300') 

data
  member_id
1       100
2       200
3   300,400
4       400
5       500
```

You need to split your comma separated values before comparing with `%in%`. I'd use an `apply` function to go through the variable, splitting (if necessary) and comparing with the `finalized_list`:

```
sapply(data$member_id, function(x) {
    any(strsplit(as.character(x), split = ',')[[1]] %in% finalized_list)
})

[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thanks a bunch.  Apologies for the imprecision in the word "list"... I don't actually know the underlying data structure of what is in these cells.  They're created in a dplyr chain where I summarize all the member_ids a given person can have via the "paste" command.  The resulting cell looks like e.g. "1300, 4000, 5000."

Answer (score 1):

first, let's make a data.frame in which one column contains lists of more than one element

```
data <- data.frame(a=c('100', '200'), b='400', c='500')
data$d <- list(list('300','400'), '600')
#     a   b   c        d
# 1 100 400 500 300, 400
# 2 200 400 500      600
```

Now we can filter these by

```
data[apply(data, 1, function(x) any(unlist(x$d) %in% finalized_list)),]
#     a   b   c        d
# 1 100 400 500 300, 400
```